# can i know the google map route of a user?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, google-maps

I want to develop a feature that allows to send a notification when the user makes a route on Google Map.

For example, the user is on google map, and when he enters the route "Los Angeles - New York", he receives a notification from my application.

my app needs to know what search the user is performing and send a notification on the same device

Comment: I’m confused, whose device sends the notification and whose receives it?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, sorry.

on a smartphone.

My application sends the notification to the same device, the user's smartphone.

Comment: No. Your app is sandboxed and can’t know what google maps is doing

Comment: can i sniffing http request of google maps ?